# Which Java compilers are available on Windows?

Tags: java

So, long story short, I need to use another Java compiler than what came with my Eclipse installation(Windows). I have to run some code that runs well in my other team member's computers (osx) but fails to run here. It seems the compiler I am using is way more strict than theirs, so I am looking for a more relaxed compiler (until they fix their code to comply to my actual compiler).

What are the options available?

So, a totally stripped down version of the code is like this:

```
public class TreeSet <E extends Xpto & IOrderable<E>> implements SortedSet<E>, Cloneable {
...
}

public interface Xpto {}

interface IOrderable<E> extends Cloneable{
    boolean greaterEq(E e);
    IOrderable<E> clone();
}
```

being the error

> "The inherited method Object.clone()
>   cannot hide the public abstract method
>   in IOrderable"

Comment: There is a lot of settings that you can play with under `Preferences > Java > Compiler` to make it "more relaxed". Out of curiosity, are you getting compile time errors for something the compile on osx ?

Comment: My team mates are using osx and it runs in their computers, yes. But strangely enough, I have other team mates that run in Windows and it runs there well, too.

Comment: Can you put a small piece of sample code that works for them but not for you?

Comment: It's a bit hard. It has a complex hierarchy of several classes. I've trimmed it down a bit. Take a look at the edit of the OP.

Comment: So, and what is the error message here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own built-in one. You should probably try using the one which comes with the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Alternatively, have you tried changing the Eclipse compiler options, there's a lot you can tweak, including whether some code ends up with errors, warnings, or nothing. Look in either the project preferences or your workspace preferences, under Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings. If you could give an example of the errors you're getting (and ideally the code which is failing), we could give more advice.

Comment: "The inherited method Object.clone() cannot hide the public abstract method in IOrderable<E>" I do understand what the problem might be, but I don't feel like fixing it. I'd really prefer to just be able to use another compiler and have it just run, if possible :( I've tried tweaking like you said but it was of no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You have these options

- [Sun/Oracle (recommended)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html)
- [IBM Jikes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jikes/)
- gjc

But your main description sounds more like build specific problem. You can tweak them by right click on the project->Properties->Java Compiler.

**UPDATE** Clonable already provides a `clone` Method which is hidden. So you should strip that line from the IOrderable interface. In TreeSet `clone` has to be public.

Comment: it builds on other people's machines and it doesn't build in mine.. yeah :(

Comment: @devoured elysium: then which compiler and IDE do they use? Do you use a build system like `ant` or `make`?

Comment: They use Eclipse, too. We aren't using any build system, just Eclipse's Build/Run command.

Comment: @devoured elysium do they use the Apple-Java implementation?

Comment: I don't know. All I know is that they are using Eclipse too.

Comment: GCJ is not an option as it isn't a Java compiler. It is part of an incomplete implementation of parts of Java.

Comment: @EJP I used it only once together with GNU Classpath when it was shipped with some linux distros - I switched back to SUNs SDK quite fast

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Ant build script, which when executed will in turn use the normal Sun Java compiler. See [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) for a simple build script. It's a good way of getting around the problems :)

Comment: i'd like to get a solution that did allow me to continue to use eclipse.

Comment: It does allow you to still use Eclipse. You just run the Ant script inside Eclipse when you want to export a jar :)

Comment: @devoured elysium: eclipse can make use of ant build scripts, they integrate quite well

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse probably uses the one in the JDK, right? (wrong. from the comments: according to 1 commenter and 3 upvoters, Eclipse uses its own internal compiler, my bad. But that means you can use the one in the JDK too :D)

Anyway, you can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCJ

Comments suggest this is not a compiler, although I do not agree. Please educate me on my wrongness and I'll gladly update or remove this answer.

From the wikipedia page :

> The GNU Compiler for Java (GCJ or gcj)
>   is a free software compiler for the
>   Java programming language and a part
>   of the GNU Compiler Collection. GCJ
>   can compile Java source code to either
>   Java Virtual Machine bytecode, or
>   directly to machine code for any of a
>   number of CPU architectures. It can
>   also compile class files containing
>   bytecode or entire JARs containing
>   such files into machine code.

Comment: Do you know, by chance, how to check which java compiler I am running on eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse uses a built-in compiler, not the JDK.

Comment: -1 for wrong answer and for introducing GCJ which isn't a Java compiler.

Comment: I would be the first one to admit that I have not a lot of experience with GCJ, but doesn't GCJ stand for "GNU Compiler for JAVA"? How is that not a Java compiler?!. Also: fixed JDK/Eclipse mistake

Comment: @Nanne (a) because it doesn't support all of Java: it only supports the CLASSPATH subset, which is pretty severe, doesn't even cover all of 1.2 let alone what was added in the four subequent major releases (b) because it has never passed the Java Compatibility Kit Test.

Comment: WIth the edited question that might all be true, but the question started out as "what options do I have". If you want to add usefull comments, why not type that last comment (it is not a complete / not a good compiler) instead of "it is not a compiler". Not helpfull at all.

Comment: @Nanne I didn't say it wasn't a compiler. I said it isn't a *Java* compiler. Statement is both true and helpful IMO.